# How to understand shellcode encoding

Tags: encoding, shellcode

I am  trying to write a simple shellcode detector.

The biggest problem for now that shellcodes might appear in encoded data during transfer and I don't know how to understand encoding. Is it possible to have that information

Answer (score 0):

Well, shellcode may be encoded by its author algorithm, or by common algorithms. I think, at least you should know about common encoding algorithms and then try to decode shellcodes.